# Ищу программу для распознавания текста с изображения

Tags: python, распознавание-символов

Python 3.7 + Win 10, нужно распознать с изображения весь текст который на ней есть.
[image: пример изображения]

Comment: https://www.simplifiedpython.net/how-to-extract-text-from-image-in-python/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установите `pytesseract` (нужно будет еще `tesseract` установить) и `pillow`:

```
pip3 install pytesseract
pip3 install pillow
```

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/7dcf8f798df79abef3862ed7586fd16ac244e4e0/pytesseract__examples__image_to_text/GTA):

```
# pip install pillow
from PIL import Image

# pip install pytesseract
# tesseract.exe from https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'


file_name = 'RuFjPBg.png'
img = Image.open(file_name)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
print(repr(text))
# '.\nCheat activated'

print(text)
# .
# Cheat activated
```